# How can I obtain a CGColor from RGB values?

Tags: ios, swift, rgb, uicolor, cgcolor

I am trying to create a custom RGB `CGColor` using Swift to use as a border color for a `UIButton`.  I've tried following code but the color is not visible:

```
var red = UIColor(red: 100.0, green: 130.0, blue: 230.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.layer.borderColor = red.CGColor
```

Is there any way to create a `CGColor` directly from RGB values?

Comment: This also confused me, looking at the docs I tried to use CGColor(red: .., green: .., blue: .., alpha: ..) However just after rereading it carefully I saw that this constructor is not available on iOS. Why are these differences? And how can I write code that runs on the Mac and on iOS as well?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You have to give the values between 0 and 1.0. So divide the RGB values by 255.

Change Your code to

```
var red = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
self.layer.borderColor = red.CGColor
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get that down to one line in Swift 3:

```
avLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.CGColor
```

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X there is `CGColorCreateGenericRGB()`, but it doesn't exist on iOS. You can use `CGColorCreate` with appropriate parameters, though.

```
self.layer.borderColor = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0])
```

The values in the array are, in order of appearance: red, green, blue, and alpha. Just like `UIColor` :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColor/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorCreate

Comment: thanks very much.  i actually found that method in the documentation but was working with iOS.  I was wondering why I was not able to use it but now you made it clear that it is just available for os x.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
UImage *newImage = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:200/255. green:228/255. blue:194/255. alpha:0.99]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you need is set the `borderWidth`, by default it is 0, so it is not visible:

```
self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Just in case you can set the `cornerRadius` if you need it rounded ... might be useful ;-)

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
```

Comment: @Shruti is correct about the `CGFloat` values you should pass to UICcolor(...)

Comment: hi.  thanks for your reply.  i had already set the borderWidth.  The answer above dividing the values by 255 was the solution i was looking for.  thx.